# Class inheritance doesn't work

Tags: typescript, angular

I am trying to build an `Icon` component that inherits properties from a base class. However, when an `Icon` is instantiated, none of the properties from `super` are present, the `__proto__` property is not set.

I feel like I'm missing something super obvious. I've run a very simple codepen version of the code and it works as expected: [CodePen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/grerwZ)

However, bringing it in to the context of Angular 2, the inherited property is always `undefined`.

BaseComponent.ts

```
export abstract class BaseComponent {
  constructor() {
    this.baseImagePath = '/Assets/Images';
  }

  baseImagePath: string;
}
```

Icon.ts

```
import {Component, Input} from 'angular2/core';
import {BaseComponent} from '../baseComponent';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-icon',
  templateUrl: 'app/components/icon/icon.tmpl.html'
})
export class Icon extends BaseComponent {
  @Input() icon: string;

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.baseImagePath += '/icons/';
  }


  getSrc() {
    return `${this.baseImagePath}${this.icon}`;
  }
}
```

I've tried moving the `this.baseImagePath += '/icons/'` line in to `ngOnInit` too just in case - it's always undefined.

Any insight in to what I'm missing would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you make a plunker?

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. Inheriting `@Input()....` and `@Component(...)` stuff is not supported but plain TS class inheritance should work without problems.

Comment: If i had to guess, your import  `import {BaseComponent} from '../baseComponent';` should probably be `import {BaseComponent} from './baseComponent';` . It works as expected in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/utCvRzeOAgJK7L6GL6xY?p=preview)

Comment: I've just made up my own plunkr and yes its working exactly as I expected. Base Component is definitely one level above the icon file, and tsc is not complaining about the import.

At least I know now that its specific to this setup and its not a TS/angular thing I don't understand.

Comment: As a follow up, I duplicated the baseComponent file, put it on the same level as icon.ts and updated the import statement and it works fine. Is there some kind of system.js magic I'm missing where it doesn't like going up a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for the trip down the rabbit hole here. Half hour of walking through the code, for whatever reason BaseComponent.ts wasn't being compiled. Run tsc a few times and it all suddenly started working.

Thanks for everyones help!